# C# Problems getting events from external DLL in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# WPF desktop application, which is using a external DLL to control a device.

Connecting to the external DLL is done with events like this (the Service object is part of the external DLL):

```
public void Init()
{
  service = new Service("service");
  service.Connected += new EventHandler(ServiceConnected);    
  service.Connect();
}

private void ServiceConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //do more stuff
}
```

This works as long I am calling from the main thread. Obviously I do not want the DLL to block the main and UI thread. So I want to put work of the device DLL in its own thread.

```
private Device device;

...

deviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitializeThread));
deviceThread.IsBackground = true;
deviceThread.Start();
...
private void InitializeThread()
{
  device = Device.MyDevice;
  device.Init();
  logger.Debug("Waiting for work . . .");
  while (running)
  {
      if (work != null)
      {
          work();

          work = null;
      }
  }
}
```

But when I try to connect to the DLL like before the event ServiceConnected is never caught in the thread. Only difference is that the Init() call is done from the new thread.

The device is a singleton in my code:

```
private Device()
{
}

public static Device MyDevice
{
    get
    {
        return Nested.instance;
    }
}

private class Nested
{
    static Nested()
    {
    }

    internal static readonly Device instance = new Device();
}
```

Why is the DLL not working in its own thread?
Are there reasons in my code?
What properties of the external DLL could cause such behavior?

Thx in advance

Comment: The Init() method must have a blocking method so it is not returning from Init.

Comment: Can you confirm on the device side that your application at least connects to it?

Comment: Yes maybe the Init() is blocking, because when I call from the main thread the main thread is blocked till ServiceConnected is called. But why is it only working on the main thread and not in a other thread.

Comment: I can confirm DLL and device are working fine.

Comment: "External DLL" is far too vague.  But sure, this is not uncommon, somebody's library is almost never thread-safe by design and may well require an STA thread with a dispatcher to work correctly.  Talk this over with the library owner before doing anything drastic.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you. I have tried to make my thread a STA thread with thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA). But this does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this simple test with a simple Service stub and the event is caught. Maybe you wants to do something different?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Device device;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread deviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitializeThread));
        deviceThread.IsBackground = true;
        deviceThread.Start();
    }

    private void InitializeThread()
    {
        device = Device.MyDevice;
        device.Init();
        /*
        while (running)
        {
           if (work != null)
           {
              work();

              work = null;
           }
        }
        */
    }
}

class Service
{
    public event EventHandler Connected;

    public Service(string name)
    {

    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Connected(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

class Device
{
    private Device()
    {
    }

    public static Device MyDevice
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Device instance = new Device();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Service service = new Service("service");
        service.Connected += new EventHandler(ServiceConnected);
        service.Connect();
    }

    private void ServiceConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do more stuff

        Console.WriteLine("ServiceConnected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I suppose in your case the Service is behaving equal when its called with or without the thread. In my case the Service is part of the external DLL and I have no control over it (except for some parameters).

Comment: I tried to put Service in an external assembly and reference it from the main project and it succeed. I think you need to investigate more deeply in your code because the code structure is correct.

Comment: Thank you - That means most likely the external DLL is causing this behavior?

Comment: I tried with Service in a separate DLL and it works. Try using a debugger and if it doesn't help try the divide and conquer approach, for example simplifying the external DLL behavior using a class stub like the one I used before. Hope it helps!

Comment: The external DLL is from a ThirdParty, so I will contact them and see if they can help...thanks so far